# Magento 2 BlockRepository.php can't understand code

Tags: repository, magento-core

I'm newbie at Magento 2, and trying to study and research code to use all business logic for my future work.

I found method getList at BlockRepository.php at https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Cms/Model/BlockRepository.php

Which doing something strange, as I think.

Here is the code (without docBlock):

```
public function getList(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $criteria)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block\Collection $collection */
    $collection = $this->blockCollectionFactory->create();

    $this->collectionProcessor->process($criteria, $collection);

    /** @var Data\BlockSearchResultsInterface $searchResults */
    $searchResults = $this->searchResultsFactory->create();
    $searchResults->setSearchCriteria($criteria);
    $searchResults->setItems($collection->getItems());
    $searchResults->setTotalCount($collection->getSize());
    return $searchResults;
}
```

As you can see, we creating collection instance and processing it, getting the ready-to-use collection in "pager" or smth else.
Why then we need to create a new instance of SearchResults and returning it instead of returning collection?
I have checked, the processed collection has the same items that the searchResults instance.

Maybe I'm new at Magento and forgot something?